# Convert pyaudio.paint16 to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pyaudio

I have data obtained by simple pyAudio recording:

```
"""PyAudio example: Record a few seconds of audio and save to a WAVE file."""

import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
  data = stream.read(CHUNK)
  frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

and I need to process these in numpy (and not to be converted back). So I need to convert from pyaudio.paInt16 (or 24 and so on...) to something more manageable like float or double.

Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is using the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/) module (disclaimer: I'm biased, since I'm its author):

```
import sounddevice as sd

CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

myrecording = sd.rec(int(RECORD_SECONDS * RATE), samplerate=RATE,
                     channels=CHANNELS, blocking=True, dtype='float64')
```

By default, this uses `float32`, but you can change the `dtype` as shown above.

Alternatively, if you actually want to convert the 16-bit values to floating-point values, have a look at [my tutorial about this topic](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb).